# What's the roadmap to reach nirvana?

Tags: lay-buddhism

Considering I don't know anything about Buddhism expect it leads to something precious called Nirvana, what should be my approach to reach there? From my experience in academics I believe reaching the peak of any field requires strong fundamentals, rigorous training/practice and then creation (ie, invention or discovery of stuff previously non existent or unknown). Does same principle applies here? Is it possible to reach the peak of Budhhist way while being a normal human (who has obligations to fulfill and lives in society) ? Do I need to join a monastery to practice Buddhism?

Comment: You cannot escape boredom. And you can be bored anywhere. I'd rather be bored in front of my computer than in a monastery where there's nothing to entertain myself with. And these days, even those esteemed monks e.g. Ajahn Brahm, etc. use computers. So, try not to escape because you can escape life only at death.

Answer (score 3):

The roadmap to nirvana is one of the most basic parts of Buddhism. It’s called the Noble Eightfold Path. It consists of:

1. right view
2. right thought
3. right speech
4. right conduct
5. right livelihood
6. right effort
7. right mindfulness
8. right passaddhi/prasrabhi (doesn’t translate to a single word in English, but has to do with practicing all four stages of dhyāna, AKA meditation)

As you might expect, it does require rigorous training. In fact, most Buddhists actually don’t reach nirvana in their current lifetime, but a lay person can reach nirvana just like monastics can.

Comment: In fact, most Buddhists actually don’t reach nirvana in their current lifetime,.... From perspective of science it's obvious that there's nothing as "next lifetime" so is there any effort in Buddhist community(in past or present) to make the process of reaching nirvana more efficient so that it can be reached in our only lifetime.

Comment: A majority of Buddhists believe in reincarnation as Hindus during the Buddha’s time taught it. It plays a lot into the concept of samsara and karma. However, some see reincarnation as less literal. Some believe that karma is one’s actions is the effect one’s actions has not only of people of today directly affected by them, but in addition, those in the distant future could be affected by that action too, similar to the Butterfly Effect. In that case, the goal would be to create a future that would expose people to the Eightfold Path.

Comment: Actually if you look at existence scientifically you will see that the "next lifetime" as you are calling it is quite assured. Observe your surroundings, now try to find any phenomena that is permanent, try to find phenomena that is not effected by causality, now try to find phenomena that does not transmigrate, Now if you cannot find any single phenomena that has these characteristics, why would you then think "you" are permanent, unaffected by causality and are unable to transmigrate...

Answer (score 0):

Nirvana comes naturally along the path who has figured out the game of life. I mean if you have ever played those games called `Grand theft Auto` or any of the massive `open world games`. Initially you are absolutely immersed in the game because it has pulled your attention so much like a black hole sucking in but after a while you get tired of repeating the same things over and over again.

The key is to trick your brain since essentially reality is more or less some kind of a simulation. You can `tune out the world` by relaxing because you have become tired of exploring stuffs in the world. Meditation is taking a break.

`Nirvana` is the realization that this life is a big fat joke. Now, you just keep doing what you are doing until you die. So, nirvana is no escape because you got stomach to feed. :)

Comment: It it's true at all, then it's just fabulous thing to do. Amazing perspective friend that.

Comment: nirvana is no escape because you got stomach to feed?

Comment: Wrong...........

Answer (score 0):

Do I need to join a monastery to practice Buddhism?
Not necessarily.

---

Buddha only encourages us to be in the present, which is the only path to Nirvana.

**How to be at present?**

Buddha teaches how to be in the present all over the **Damma**. (Buddha's teachings.)
It's about concentration. It's about knowing what's going on in you, around you. (Not dreaming about the past and future.)
You can practice **Samatha meditation** to get absolute concentration.
(This is not the true purpose of Buddha's teaching.)

**Nirvana?**

Now, One should use this concentration/ability to be in the present to understand the **Four Noble Truths**(Nirvana).

Which is **vipassana meditation** (The process of using concentration to understand the Four Noble Truths).

Which is the **main goal of Buddhism**.

After someone attains Nirvana, they won't rebirth again. So **No suffering, No purpose for living, rebirth, death**.

Thanks . Any questions are welcome. ☸.